# I am not able to access django inside virtual environment

Tags: python, django, web-applications, frameworks, virtualenv

If I install django on local system, then that django, if I access in virtual environment, will that be accessible, or I have to install django again in VirtualEnvironment?

Comment: It was to be in whatever environment your currently using.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install Django in you virtual environment .

Example virtualenv (env) on Windows

```
env\Scrips\activate

pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the behaviour you want, you can set the `system-site-packages` option when you create the virtual environment. See the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments). This will give the virtual environment access to the system site-packages dir.

Answer (score 0):

Any virtual environment starts out essentially blank, with no packages installed, so you will have to install Django again in the environment.

Part of the reasoning for this is because if you install something with pip outside of a virtual environment, there's a chance that another python package or program somewhere might break -- this can be from namespace pollution (installing multiple modules that are imported in the same way but work differently) or having different versions of the software (an update breaks some functionality that something else relies on). Even if Django itself doesn't break anything, some dependency it has might be able to.

Another advantage is that you can always run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in your environment to list all installed packages and versions, then `pip install -r requirements.txt` in another environment. This makes package import and versioning effortless when you move among development machines or between development and production, and helpful if you'd ever like to roll your own package.